# Porting EvoSuite to java 17?

Tags: unit-testing, java-17, evosuite, java-21

Is there any chance that the roadmap of EvoSuite contains a support for higher java version?
I'd be interested for java 17 and java 21.

I looked at the evosuite github that says is supports java 8 and 9 (the latest release is from 2021 though), and some comment that says about java 11, but not further info.

Comment: I know the EvoSuite homepage directs you here for "general questions", but that's really not the kind of question that belongs on SO. This is something that *only* the developers of EvoSuite can answer (unless it's already been publicly discussed somewhere), so [their mailinglist](https://groups.google.com/g/evosuite) is probably much better suited for this question.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this asks about non-public plans of some project.